# Sass "@at-root" not working

Tags: sass

Currently I have sass 3.3 installed but I am using compass to compile. The question at hand is , I have the following two mixins to do bem syntax:

```
//elements get appended with "__" and the $name
=e($name)
    @at-root &__#{$name}
        @content

//modifiers get appended with "--" and the $name
=m($name)
    @at-root &--#{$name}
        @content
```

In use:

```
.blocker
    +e(item)
        color: red
```

Output:

```
.blocker {
  @at-root &__item {
    color: blue;
}

}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: What version of Compass are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your mixin out an it seems to work fine, however, using the updated sass syntax, you don't need a mixin or @at-root to achieve this

```
.blocker
    &__item
        color: red 
    &--mod
        color: blue
```

will compile to

```
.blocker__item {
    color: blue;
}
.blocker--mod {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to try out the sass code itself, independently of your environment, take a look at [SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and wonder why it's not working.  Here is the gist - http://sassmeister.com/gist/2ec20689a0b33427dee7

Comment: @SatheeshKumar on sassmeister you need to change the settings of your gist from SCSS to Sass. Then the spacing needs to be consistent, either indenting with 2 spaces or 4. After this it compiled for me